# JQuery - Fullpage page scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

```
    <div id="fullpage" class="fullpage">
    <div class="section inf-sky-silder row-fluid">
        Section one
    </div>
    <div class="section inf-sky-silder row-fluid">
            Section one
    </div>
    <div class="section inf-sky-silder row-fluid">
            Section one
    </div>
    </div>
    <p> This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
            This section is using `data-percentage="80"` and `data-centered="false"`. It won't be vertically centered in the viewport and will show part of the previous or next section depending on the direction of the previous scroll.
    </p>
```

Hey guys I'm creating a complicated thing in my project. In one of my project I need two more section with fullpage scroll functionality. When this function finished the page should normally scroll to other sections. Can we do that? I have attached my test work link with this post. Can you go through it and help me?

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/single-scroll/

This is also a reference. I need this kind of functionality.
https://codepen.io/50foot/full/ZJwERV

Thanks :)

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that fullPage.js provides.

The most you can is make use of the fullpage.js option `scrollOverflow` as [in this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Comment: Hi Alvaro, so do I want to purchase that extension? That's what you are saying?

Comment: Nop. That's not an extension. Just an option that requieres an external file. 
It is free :)